# Google Chrome Extension - waiting until page loads

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome Extension, I have a [Content Script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) (content.js) and a [Background Page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) (background.html). I have context.js checking for a keyword that appears on the page. However, I want to wait until the page is fully loaded until I search the page, because the keyword may occur at the bottom of the page.

See [Page action by content](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html) sandwich example ([files](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_content/)), this is basically what I am doing. If you load the extension you'll see the extension only works when the word "sandwich" appears at the top of the page.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to add this to the "content_scripts" part of your manifest.json file.

```json
"run_at": "document_end"
```

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to manifest's `"run_at": "document_end"`, there could be applied a standard javascript event handling approach. For example, [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event could be used to run the logic that requires loaded DOM.

**manifest.json**

```json
    "content_scripts": [
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ]
```

**content.js**

```js
    console.log('The extension works');
    // ... logic that does not need DOM
    
    function run() {
      console.log('The DOM is loaded');
      // ... logic that needs DOM
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", run);
```

Comment: did you mean `"run_at": "document_end"` instead of `"run_at": "document_start"`?

Comment: I don't think so.