# Run a loop after page loads Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im making a google chrome extension and i need to edit part of a page after it loads. How would I run a check to see if the page loads before running a loop? Here's the loop I want to run after the page loads.

```
function go()
{

    for(i=0; i<=(array.length-1); i++)
{
    try
    {
        Checks();
        SendToCookie();
    }

    catch(error)
    {
        alert(error);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: So you want to register an event to listen for page load?

Comment: Im not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome content scripts are loaded after the DOM is loaded by default.  See the `run_at` section of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.

> The browser chooses a time to inject scripts between "document_end"
>   and immediately after the window.onload event fires. The exact
>   moment of injection depends on how complex the document is and how
>   long it is taking to load, and is optimized for page load speed.

This means that you can just run your loop, and it should work as you'd expect from using a regular onload method.

Answer (score 0):

Possible dupplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019395/google-chrome-extension-waiting-until-page-loads)

Add this line to the "content_scripts" part of your manifest.json file.

[Source (Content Script Documentation)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: Ok, now you can flag duplicates yourself with 50 rep (a comment is created automatically when you flag as duplicate)

Comment: Hahaha sorry, I just got to 50 like a minute ago, will do!

Comment: Don't worry, it's alright :)