# Get HTML element via aria label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm making a small chrome extension and for it I need to grab a `div` from the DOM to manipulate. I get the DOM but I'm having trouble grabbing the required `div`. Here's the code for it.

```
<div id=":ik" class="Am Al editable LW-avf" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 137px;"><br></div>
```

I've tried `getElemenyByID`, and `document.attrib` but both return `null`. Any advice on how to get the value of the text that will be input inside this `div`?

Comment: For Gmail right?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` with an attribute selector should do it:

```
// The first element that matches (or null if none do):
var element = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Message Body"]');
// A list of matching elements (empty if none do):
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Message Body"]');
```

Or if that ID is stable, simply:

```
var element = document.getElementById(":ik");
```

(Note that the `d` is lower case; you have it in upper case in your example.)

Either way, make sure your code doesn't run until the page is loaded, by including this in your manifest:

```
"run_at": "document_end"
```

*(A little)* more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042885/157247), which references [this Google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Sometimes the aria label might change but have a static prefix, for cases like this you could do `document.querySelector('[aria-label^="Message Body"]')`

Answer (score 15):

Probably you're trying to get the Element before it's even loaded on the page.

If so, you can wrap your code into the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById(':ik').textContent);
});
```

---

But if you really want to get the element by its `aria` label, you can do that:

```
document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Message Body"]');
```

But this way is much less performatic, and you'll need to do exactly what I've mentioned above too.

Comment: +1 for an answer that does not depend on jQuery. Regular JavaScript can get the job done too, without needing an entire library.

Answer (score -6):

this is the permenent solution check it it will work forever

```
var getElementsByAttribute = function (attr, value) {
var match = [];

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var ii = 0, ln = elements.length; ii < ln; ii++) {

if (elements[ii].hasAttribute(attr)) {

  /* If a value was passed, make sure it matches the element's */
  if (value) {

    if (elements[ii].getAttribute(attr) === value) {
      match.push(elements[ii]);
    }
    } else {

    match.push(elements[ii]);
  }
}
 }
  return match;
};

(function () {
  var baz = getElementsByAttribute('data-foo', 'bar');
  for (var xx = 0, ln = baz.length; xx < ln; xx++) {
    baz[xx].innerHTML = 'These *are* the droids we are looking for!';
 }
})();
```

Comment: How does it answer the question? Although there are some specific selector syntaxes available as the other answer suggested, why one should reinvent?

Comment: This is not even an answer