# Aria selector not finding element on FB

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've never made a chrome extension and only coded a little js, I wanted to remove the 'watch' tab from facebook when the page loads. (What I really wanna do is remove the red badge telling you that there is new pointless videos you have not asked for; The below is me trying to accomplish this)

```
<a aria-label="Watch" class="oajrlxb2 <-- Omitted jumbled classes --> g5ia77u1" href="/watch/" role="link" tabindex="0" aria-current="page"><span class="l9j0dhe7"><!--$--><svg viewBox="0 0 28 28" class="a8c37x1j ms05siws hwsy1cff b7h9ocf4 aaxa7vy3" height="28" width="28"></svg><span class="pmk7jnqg h5g66v2i nezaghv5"><!--$--><!--/$--></span><!--/$--></span></a>
```

From inspect in chrome I get the above element and figure that's the one I want to hide. I set up the extension according to some guide and it's running, I've tried several variations on the below script to hide the tab:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[aria-label='Watch']").style.visibility = "hidden"
    $("[aria-label='Watch']").style.display = "block"
    $("[aria-label='Watch']").style.display = "none"
})
```

The error I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined
```

So the selector which I got from [this and similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733897/get-html-element-via-aria-label) is not working. I suspect my selector problem is unrelated to the 'aria' property as i tried to select on some of the fb- jumbled classes as well and that did result in the same error

Edit, here's the current manifest file after attempt to scrap js and do it only in css:

```
{
  "name": "Hide unwanted tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.facebook.com/*"
      ],
      "css": ["hide_watch.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And css file:

```
[ariaLabel="Watch"]
{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Facebook is a modern site that generates its UI using a page script and that happens long after DOMContentLoaded or window's load event. You should detect the moment a DOM element appears by using MutationObserver. There's a much simpler solution for the problem though: you can hide the element using a CSS file and specify it in manifest's `content_scripts` section.

Comment: Changed to only css solution, seemed like a good choice. Im getting no errors now, but from what I can see the html element is not receiving my css,`[ariaLabel="Watch"]{ visibility: hidden;display: none;}`. In the inspect window in chrome you can see 'crossed-out' overridden styles, but I don't see mine there as overridden.

Comment: Try raising specificity via `!important` or even the `:not` hack, examples should be easy to find.