# Javascript getAttribute not evaluating to string value in if statement

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to loop through the tabs on a page and figure out which one is selected (I am using a Tab container on oracle APEX) and the active tab has attribute aria-selected as true so I am looking for that.

I've tried the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('t-Tabs-link').length; i++) {
    if (console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('t-Tabs-link')[i].getAttribute('aria-selected')) === 'true') {
        console.log('here');
    }
    else {
        console.log('not here');
    }
}
```

However, as you can see in the image below everything is evaluating to not true, even the tab that has the attribute as true. If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong I'd be very grateful.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZoaQ.png)

Comment: You can simply query directly on the aria value. see: [Get HTML element via aria label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733897/get-html-element-via-aria-label)

Comment: `console.log` always returns `undefined`, so comparing `console.log(…) === 'true'` is pointless. Remove the logging and the code will work.

Comment: Also don't call `.getElementsByClassName()` over and over again like that.

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks for explaining the console.log issue

Answer (score 0):

use a `forEach` loop instead of `for` loop, its more clear and direct in its purpose

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.t-Tabs-link').forEach(function(tab) {
    if (tab.getAttribute('aria-selected') === 'true') {
        console.log(tab.innerText, 'is selected');
    } else { console.log(tab.innerText, 'is not selected'); }
});
```

```html
      <a class="t-Tabs-link" aria-selected="false">Tab 1</a>
      <a class="t-Tabs-link" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
      <a class="t-Tabs-link" aria-selected="true">Tab 3</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the alternate method, I'm very new to javascript.

Comment: Better use  `for … of` loop instead of the `.forEach()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you store the links in a variable it's easier to see what you're doing. You just had a couple typos in your for loop:

```js
const tabsLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('t-Tabs-link');

for (var i = 0; i < tabsLinks.length; i++) 
{
  if (tabsLinks[i].getAttribute('aria-selected') === 'true') 
  {
    console.log('here');
  } 
  else 
  {
    console.log('not here');
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="t-Tabs-link" aria-selected="false">Tab 1</a>
<a class="t-Tabs-link" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
<a class="t-Tabs-link" aria-selected="true">Tab 3</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote anything let since this is a new account but this worked