# Javascript unable to read values from getElementById instantly on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read the value from getElementById and make an alert message after making a refresh. With static values, there is no issue but while reading it from getElementById it does not perform the same as static values. For instance, my code is like this

```
var sendCode  = 'var x = document.getElementById("sumPendingLabel").innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""); document.title=x; window.alert(x);';
```

If I pass a value to document.title = 1 and window.alert(1), I am getting the desired result. But above code not giving desired result. Although after changing tab and coming back to the current tab it gives the desired tab. But I want changes in the current tab instantly as it happens for the static values.

Comment: You may be executing this code before the page has loaded, [try doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019395/google-chrome-extension-waiting-until-page-loads)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wait till the document has fully loaded (or at least the DOM has) before doing any JavaScript.

So `<body></body>` should be `<body onload="docLoaded()"></body>`

Alternatively, you could do this using JS by having

```js
window.addEventListener("load", docLoaded, false);
function docLoaded() {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Or, if you have some media and would rather just want to wait for the DOM to load, use

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", domLoaded, false);
function domLoaded() {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Edit: `var x = document.getElementById("sumPendingLabel").innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");` is incorrect and has to be something like:
`var x = document.getElementById("sumPendingLabel").innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");` 
or
 `var x = document.getElementById("sumPendingLabel").textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");`